# Installing rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, installation

I'm trying to use Rails, when I do this system says the following

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
```

Then I run - sudo gem install rails
and as the result I got

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.5/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Are you logged in as the root user? Google says amongst other things :http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=22116

Answer (score 3):

You're a Mac user. The 'common build tools', known as the 'BSD subsytem' in the Xcode package are often outdated. For example the installed ruby is at version 1.8. Do yourself a huge favor and install the common build tools via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager. After that I suggest installing a newer version of ruby as rails will soon drop support for the 1.8 series that you're using. Different version of ruby are installed using the [ruby version manager](https://rvm.io)

After installing [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and [rvm](https://rvm.io) you have rock solid base! Installing a ruby version is now just a matter of running `rvm install 1.9.2` and you'll get the latest patch version of the 1.9.2 series of the MRI.

With ruby 1.9.2 you will have no problem installing the current version of RubyOnRails.

This chain if tools is what most Ruby/Rails devs use today.

Answer (score 0):

he got problems with installing the json gem. I resolved that issue by installing the Ruby DevKit.

Download form here:

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Install tutorial here:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-kit

Cheers Stefan

Comment: unfortunately I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.3